# How to launch several python programs through another python program

Tags: python, multithreading, aiogram

I need to make a program that would run three telegram bots in different threads and make sure that the processes are running. In the future, it is planned to make the main bot, from which it would be possible to manage three processes and check whether they are working.
This is what my project structure looks like:

```
BOTS_SYSTEM
├ main.py
└ main bots
  ├ __init__.py
  ├ BOT1
    ├ __init__.py
    ├ bot.py
    ├ config.py
    ├ create_bot.py
    ├ handlers.py
    ├ keyboard.py
    └ ... 
  ├ BOT2
    └ ...
  └ BOT3
    └ ...
```

main.py code looks like:

```
import threading
import asyncio
from main_bots.BOT1 import bot as bot1

if __name__ == '__main__':
   x = threading.Thread(target=bot1.run())
   x.start()
   x.join()
```

bot.py code:

```
import asyncio
import handlers#, admin
from create_bot import dp

async def main():
    handlers.register_handlers(dp)
    #admin.register_handlers(dp)
    await dp.start_polling()

def run():
    asyncio.run(main())
```

And create_bot.py:

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from config import config

bot = Bot(token=config().get_token())
dp=Dispatcher(bot, storage=MemoryStorage())
```

I was planning to run three of my bots through the threading module, but ran into the problem that python doesn't see the imports inside these bots, giving me the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'create_bot'
```

Please advise me the solution to this problem!

Comment: when you use `from x import y` it wont run the entire script, so the imports don't happen

Comment: @AnthonyL I don't think that's the problem. If you run bot.py, that particular bot starts and runs fine

Comment: imports are so annoying! I think you need to import BOT1, and tell what's being 'exported' in the `__init__.py` file.. something like this

Comment: @AnthonyL So far nothing works. Could you please explain what you mean?

Comment: The root (main.py) doesn't know where `create_bot` is when it runs `bot.py` from its location, but if you import `BOT1` and put the `create_bot` import inside `BOT1.__init__.py` then the import will be brought along

Comment: If you haven't made progress, the bots could be ran directly using the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module to avoid the imports